# How are images shown in the terminal

Tags: linux, image, terminal, w3m

Some packages like w3m-img, fim, lsix etc can be used to show the images directly on the terminal itself on linux.

I am not talking about converting the image into an ASCII character version and showing it but the image itself which looks proper without any the artifacts.

so how do these programs actually draw the images onto the terminal?

Comment: You'd have to read the source code to see ([this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265518/how-can-i-display-image-clearly-in-xterm/265574#265574) points to relevant source).

Answer (score -1):

I've used [Feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) in the past. It should be already installed on popular Linux distributions. To use it, simply do the following:

```
feh your-image.jpeg
```

Comment: i know that we can view images with feh. but it opens in a separate window. w3m-img can display images in the terminal itself. i want to know how is that achieved underneath the hood

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you want to see the images. Can't help you with how everything works under the hood, that's a lot of libraries to uncover. Don't the listed packages you've mentioned in your question have github repos and further documentation?

Comment: yeah. but i am not that good with understanding libs used for X and all, i tried going through it but it just went over my head. just wanted a general overview of how it is accomplished